# Comparing multiple strings in a pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame in Python3.x, with several numeric columns and two columns with strings:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dict = {"numericvals": np.repeat(25, 8), 
    "numeric":np.repeat(42, 8), 
    "first":["beneficiary, duke", "compose", "herd primary", "stall", "deep", "regular summary classify", "timber", "property”], 
    "second": ["abcde”, "abcde”, "abcde”, "abcde”, "abcde”, "abcde”, "abcde”, "abcde”]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

df = df[['numeric', 'numericvals', 'first', 'second']]

print(df)
   numeric  numericvals                     first second
0       42           25         beneficiary, duke  abcde
1       42           25                   compose  abcde
2       42           25              herd primary  abcde
3       42           25                     stall  abcde
4       42           25                      deep  abcde
5       42           25  regular summary classify  abcde
6       42           25                    timber  abcde
7       42           25                  property  abcde
```

The column `first` contains one or more strings. If there are more that one, these are separated by either a space or comma.

My goal is to create a column recording the length of strings in `first` which are longer or shorter in length than the strings in `second`. If these are the same size, this case should be ignored.

My idea would be to create two lists:

```
longer = []
shorter = []
```

If the string in `first` is longer, append the string length via `len()` in `longer`. If the string is shorter, record the string length in `short` via `len()`.

Here is how the analysis should look like (in pandas DataFrame format):

```
   numericvals numeric                   first second  longer  shorter
0          25      42        beneficiary, duke abcde  11       4
1          25      42                  compose abcde  7        0
2          25      42             herd primary abcde  7        4
3          25      42                    stall abcde  0        0
4          25      42                     deep abcde  0        4
5          25      42 regular summary classify abcde  7, 7, 8  0
6          25      42                   timber abcde  6        0
7          25      42                 property abcde  8        0
```

I don't know how to deal with multiple strings in `first`, especially if there are 3. How should one do this comparison in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` [(source)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
import operator

def transform(df, op):
    lengths = [len(s) for s in df['first'].replace(',', ' ').split()]
    return [f for f in lengths if op(f, len(df.second))] or [0]

df['longer']  = df.apply(transform, axis=1, args=[operator.gt])
df['shorter'] = df.apply(transform, axis=1, args=[operator.lt])
```

This should work for any amount of strings, assuming any space or comma indicates a new string.

Here is the output:

```
   numeric  numericvals                     first second     longer shorter
0       42           25         beneficiary, duke  abcde       [11]     [4]
1       42           25                   compose  abcde        [7]     [0]
2       42           25              herd primary  abcde        [7]     [4]
3       42           25                     stall  abcde        [0]     [0]
4       42           25                      deep  abcde        [0]     [4]
5       42           25  regular summary classify  abcde  [7, 7, 8]     [0]
6       42           25                    timber  abcde        [6]     [0]
7       42           25                  property  abcde        [8]     [0]
```

I tried my best.  Hope this helps!